# Solr 3.4 group.truncate does not work with facet queries

Tags: filter, solr, grouping, facet

When using Grouping with `group.truncate=true`, The following simple facet query:

```
facet.query=Monitor_id:[380000 TO 400000]
```

Doesn't give the same number as the `nGroups` result for the equivalent filter query:

```
fq=Monitor_id:[380000 TO 400000]
```

I thought they should be the same - from the [Wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing):

```
group.truncate: If true, facet counts are based on the most relevant document of each group matching the query.
```

What am I doing wrong?

If I turn off `group.truncate` then the counts are the same, as I'd expect - but unfortunately I'm only interested in the grouped results.

Thanks!

Comment: According to the solr-user mailing list, this is a bug in Solr. I have logged it here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2863.
Question is now: can anyone think of a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug, but a missing feature as has been described in [SOLR-2863](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2863). As described in the issue Lucene needs to support matrix grouped facet counts. This feature can be tracked in [LUCENE-3097](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3097).